# covert json int array to continues String of integer

Tags: java, json

I have the folowing json `{"movieList":"[4,5,12]"}` and I need to convert to continues String like `"4,5,12"`

How to do that?

Comment: If I was nasty, I'd suggest using `json.substring(15,21)` but seriously, we need more context on the libs you use, etc.

Comment: Or if you have a dynamic array inside a string you can do String elementArray=obj .getJSONObject("movieList"); String arrayStringify=elementArray.substring(1, elementArray.length()-1));

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that your JSON data is in incorrect format.

The right format is  `'{"movieList":[4,5,12]}'` . To convert JSON int array to string i used this method.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#converter').click(function(){
jsonData ='{"movieList":[4,5,12]}'
alert("JSON data is" + jsonData);
var parsedata= $.parseJSON(jsonData);

var finalString= parsedata.movieList.toString();
alert("String is" + finalString);
});
});
</script>
<body>

<div class="table-responsive container">
<input type=button id="converter" text="Switch Mode" value="Convert" >
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```